# SPFx Form Customizer - is it possible to customize Site Pages forms or it has to be list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-form, form, applicationcustomizers, form-customization

Is it possible to use Form Customizer for Site Pages library or it has to be a list?

How would properties look like, is this right?

```
  "serveConfigurations": {
        "default": {
          "pageUrl": "https://mySite.com/sites/mySubsite/_layouts/15/SPListForm.aspx",
          "formCustomizer": {
            "ContentTypeID": "0x0101009D1CB255DA76424F860D91F20E6C4118006CA2BEE5D9A8C142A32C154E21BEEE45",
            "componentId": "0d1733c0-760a-4e3c-9fcd-2b64e261b635",
            "PageType": 8,
            "RootFolder": "/sites/mySubsite/SitePages/"
          }
        }
```

What would be link to access modified form page?

That way I get following message in browser:

```
Sorry, something went wrong
An unexpected error has occurred.
```

Comment: I have not tried for document libraries but based on the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions): Form Customizer Provides a way to assoicate and override default new, edit and view form experience of list and **libraries** with custom forms by associating component to content type.